# Pausing / Stopping evaluateScript in JSContext

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

Is it possible to pause and resume or even just stop the evaluateScript function. This would be useful in my app because some of the JS code being evaluated might take a while to execute and the user may want to go do other things then come back later to the same state.

**Example Code**

```
let jsSource = "some JavaScript code"
let context = JSContext()
context?.evaluateScript(jsSource)
```

**What I want**

```
context.pause()
context.resume()
context.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or [async, await API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [Callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) to wait for your function to complete, then execute another piece of code. You cannot pause, stop, reasume in JavaScript.